# Converting now-30d to double using Nest 6.x

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

All,
    I am working on a Nest 6.x query that produces the flowing DSL on a date field in Elastic search. The Nest api only allows a double value for the GreaterThanOrEquals() on the date field. How can I convert the DateMath type that produces now-30d/d to a double? Please see my code below

Query DSL

```
{
    "range": {
        "agreementCancelDate": {
            "gte": "now-30d/d"
        }
    }
}
```

Nest

```
f.Range(r => r.Field("agreementCancelDate").GreaterThanOrEquals(d))
```

d above must be the double value representation of now-30d/d.

I am using the following code to create now-30d/d using Nest.DateMath api

```
var aMonthBack = Nest.DateMath.Now.Subtract("30d").RoundTo(DateMathTimeUnit.Day);
```

Older version of NEST( 1.7x) was allowing me to enter a string value like "now-30d/d", but 6.x takes only a double value

In the Nest code above, f is QueryContainerDescriptor

Answer (score 1):

The constraints on [a `range` query on `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/date-range-query-usage.html) properties accepts a `DateMath` argument, which has an implicit conversion from a `string`

```
public class MyDocument 
{
    public DateTime AgreementCancelDate { get; set; }
}

var client = new ElasticClient();

client.Search<MyDocument>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .DateRange(dr => dr
            .Field(f => f.AgreementCancelDate)
            .GreaterThanOrEquals("now-30d/d")
        )
    )
);
```

which produces the request

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "agreementCancelDate": {
        "gte": "now-30d/d"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: perfect. Thanks Russ Cam